# Проверка сервера клиентом и наоборот при утсановлении https соединения vertx

Tags: java, ssl, https, vert.x

Прошу знающих людей объяснить мне некоторые вещи, связаныне с ssl в фреймфорке Vertx.

Я хочу установить https соединение между клиентом и сервером, да ещё такое, чтобы не только сервер проверял открытый ключ клиента, но и чтобы клиент проверял сервер.

С первой часью я справился легко, добавив на сервер закрытый ключ, на клиент открытый в опицях, так же предварительно указав там, что соединение будет ssl. Vertx стал автоматически проверять публичый ключ клиента.

А вот со второй частью я уже не могу справиться т.к. добавив свой приватный ключ клиенту, а публичный отдав серверу, и так же настроив всё в опциях, клиент не првоеряет сервер. Пробовал подменять ключ на неверный у сервера, клиенту вообще пофиг.

Так же есть свойство в опицях, чтобы установить првоерку хоста. Если я ставлю эту опцию, то вообще соединение не устанавливается.

Скажите, пожалуйста,  связана ли проверка хоста у клиента в vertx с проверкой публичного ключа с севрера и как вообще можно организовать данную проверку.

Опции сервера:

```
new HttpServerOptions()
    .setSsl(true)
    .setKeyStoreOption(
       new JksOptions()
            ...
    )
    .setTrustStoreOption(
       new JksOptions()
            ...
    )
    .setPort(port)
    .setHost(host);
```

Опции клиента:

```
new HttpClientoptions()
    .setSsl(true)
    .setTrustStoreOption(
       new JksOptions()
            ...
    )
    .setKeyStoreOption(
       new JksOptions()
            ...
    )
    .setVerifyHost(true)
    .setkeepAlive(true);
```

Comment: Вам надо для начала разобраться в чем вообще смысл ключей и сертификатов. Свой приватный ключ (серверный, насколько я понимаю) нельзя добавлять клиенту. На то он и приватный. И Вы скорее всего добавили на клиент публичный ключ сервера, а еще точнее в траст стор на стороне клиента добавили сертификат с публичным ключом сервера. Это надо, чтобы клиент проверял подлинность сервера, а не для того чтобы сервер проверял клиента.

Comment: Нет-нет, должно быть вы меня не так поняли.

У сервера свой приватный ключ, а клиента свой приватный ключ и они поделились друг с другом публичными ключами для взаимной проверки.

Это ведь  должно так работать?

Comment: Да. Не просто ключами, а сертификатами. Иначе сервер не может быть уверен, что ключ присланный клиентом действительно был прислан тем субъектом кем он себя заявил.

Comment: Ну вроде с этой точки зрения я всё сделал так, только сертефикаты у меня самоподписаныне.

Не могли бы вы подсказать. как со стороны vertx-а это правльно добавить в опции и организовать взаимную проверку ?

VerifyHost как-то может в этом помочь ?

Comment: Может, если серверный сертификат проверяется, то клиента можно и по паролю пустить; соединение то зашифровано уже

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже опции были заданы мной не совсем верно при настройке клиента и сервера.

**Исправленные**

Опции сервера:

```
new HttpServerOptions()
    .setSsl(true)
    .setKeyStoreOption(
       new JksOptions()
            ...
    )
    .setTrustStoreOption(
       new JksOptions()
            ...
    )
    .setClientAuth(ClientAuth.REQUIRED)
    .setPort(port)
    .setHost(host);
```

Опции клиента:

```
new HttpClientoptions()
    .setSsl(true)
    .setTrustStoreOption(
       new JksOptions()
            ...
    )
    .setKeyStoreOption(
       new JksOptions()
            ...
    )
    .setVerifyHost(false)
    .setkeepAlive(true);
```

Добавил ещё один пункт .setClientAuth(ClientAuth.REQUIRED) и проверка работает.

Не до конца уверен, но по крайней мере при подмене ключей оно хотя бы ругается и не даёт установить соединение